# LVL Working fine when build in Eclipse, when build with ant for release get COULD NOT BIND TO SERVICE ERROR

Tags: android, service, bind, keystore

I have an app that builds and runs fine using LVL from within eclipse.

When I build it using ant, adding obvuscation and my own signing the app responds when attempting to check the LVL license as COULD NOT BIND TO SERVICE.. exact error:

06-16 15:04:37.289: WARN/ActivityManager(62): Unable to start service Intent { act=com.a.a.a.f }: not found
06-16 15:04:37.299: ERROR/LicenseChecker(488): Could not bind to service.

I don't understand, the app runs fine if I take out the checker code, my call to do the LVL check is

```
    mChecker = new LicenseChecker( 
            this, new ServerManagedPolicy(getApplicationContext(), 
                    new AESObfuscator(SALT, getPackageName(), androidId)),
                    BASE64_PUBLIC_KEY  
                    );
     mChecker.checkAccess(mLicenseCheckerCallback);
```

There are only 2 differences between Eclipse Generated and my own Generated code, that being that I am using obvuscation which isn't the issue because the code does run, and that I use my own signature vs the developer one.

Also, if I EXPORT the APK and have it use the keystore the ANT is using (or at least should be using) and install that APK all works fine... so it seems like maybe my ant build it grabbing the wrong keystore file.  That's all I can think of. Anyone have any other ideas?  Know where I should check in the build scripts for where its looking for the Keystore?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I created a new keystore with a different name, and modified my ant build to use this one, and confirmed it is using this one and still I get this error when I build with ANT... So its not the keystore. When I export from eclipsed signed with this keystore everything works, as before... So, this now points to obvuscation??  That's the only thing that is left different.

Comment: figured it out, it was indeed the obvuscation...

Comment: Add Full solution when I am allowed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nevermind, I found the answer, it was indeed the obvuscation:

Add the following to the proguard config.txt file

-keep public interface com.android.vending.licensing.ILicensingService